# .gitignore *.user ignoring new files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a .NET project in Visual Studio 2019 and am using a git repo via Azure Dev Ops to track the code.

I have noticed that when I add a new file to the project, in this case .cs files, they are being ignored.

I ran:

```
git check-ignore -v filename
```

This told me that the line in the .gitignore it had a problem with was with ***.user**

Does anyone know why this is this causing .cs files to be ignored?

Removing it fixes the issue.

You can see this in the default file for Visual Studio: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: You are using the `Visual Studio` .gitignore?

Comment: I generally like to use the .gitignore DevOps generates for new repos.  It has all the defaults for VS.  Maybe create a new repo, generate a .gitignore and copy it?

Comment: The .gitignore was created by Azure dev ops. I just can't work out why that particular line is causing this. I don't like NOT knowing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that in my folder path I had the word **user**. It was ignoring anything after that.